# QML - How to use GridView::itemAt(real x, real y)?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

I can get item of `Repeater` like this:

```
var item = repeater.itemAt(index);
```

But how can I get item of `GridView`? I saw [itemAt function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#itemAt-method). But it is different from `itemAt` of `Repeater`. It wants `x` and `y` coordinates but we can use index in `GridView` like `Repeater`. How can I access the item?

**Edit:**

```
gridView.currentIndex = index;
var a = gridView.currentItem;
gridView.currentIndex = lastIndex;
var b = gridView.currentItem;
if (a.imageSource === b.imageSource) console.log('Equals!');
```

I'm always seeing `Equals!` output. But they (images) aren't equals (a has 1.png, b has 2.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no build in function for that, but you may try this approach:

```
gridView.currentIndex = index; // your index
var item = gridView.currentItem;

// reset the current index to the previous value if you have to
```

Maybe this will also work instead (not tested):

```
var item = gridView.children[index];
```

That is more like a work around but should work in your case.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't access items with these.

Comment: What do you mean you can't access them? Why not it's documented in Qt doc or do you want something else?

Comment: What model are you using for that `GridView`, usually I'd like to access the model directly if I need some data (you don't need the view for that). It's better then getting some value from a view component.

Comment: Oh thanks. I checked my code now and reason of the problem is `imageSource` property. I access the property and problem solved. I tried your first method, it's running. Thank you again.